# Experimenting with a OOP design pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object-oriented

Initially, I was using the `class` syntax to structure my code. While it sure did feel nice to work with, I found it lacked some important functionalities, like private properties and interfaces. Things that I had found useful in other OOP languages like Java.

I understand JavaScript doesn't have classes, I'm trying here to experiment with prototypes. So this thread belongs more to [Prototypal Class Design](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/object-oriented/info) (no documentation there...).

I'm going for a [Factory Function design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)), here are some of the advantages of using such technique to construct a "class" in JavaScript:

- **the factory and its instances can enclose private variables**. This solves the problem of not having actual private instance/static properties usually seen in OOP languages.
- we **have control over the object's prototype** allowing us to combine prototypes from different factories. This makes it possible to "extend" factories with more properties/methods or mix multiple prototypes together similar to how interfaces work in OOP languages.
- we can **keep a good structure for our factories**, if we extend a factory with some methods, the instances coming from this new extended factory will remain as an instance of the initial factory. In other words, the opertator `instanceof` will still work.

---

I have implemented such design using a IIFE wrapping the actual factory function. Here's the initial factory called **Person**, and below a factory called **Singer** which extends **Person**'s factory.

```js
const Person = (function() {

  // private shared variables
  let total = 0;
  let average = 0;
  const updateAverage = function() {
    average = total / Person.count;
  }

  // public static attributes
  Person.count = 0;
  Person.prototype = {
    sayHi() {
      return `Hi, I'm ${this.name}`;
    }
  }

  function Person(name, age) {

    // private instance variables       

    // public instance attributes
    const properties = {
      name,
      gapToAverage() {
        return Math.abs(age - average);
      }
    }

    // some logic
    Person.count += 1;
    total += age;
    updateAverage();

    // return the instance
    return Object.create(
      Object.create(Person.prototype),              // Person's prototype
      Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(properties)  // Person's own public instance properties
    );

  }

  // return the constructor
  return Person;

})();
```

```js
const Singer = (function() {

  let songs = {};

  const prototypeExtension = {
    sing(song) {
      return songs[song];
    }
  }

  // extend Person's prototype
  Singer.prototype = Object.create(
    Person.prototype,
    Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(prototypeExtension)
  );

  function Singer(name, age, songs) {

    const properties = {
      getSongTitles() {
        return Object.keys(songs);
      }
    }

    // return the instance
    return Object.assign(
      Object.create(Singer.prototype),  // Singer's prototype
      Person(name, age),                // Person's public instance properties
      properties                        // Singer's own public instance properties
    );

  }

  // return the constructor
  return Singer;

})();
```

This is considered the best approach to object-oriented programming in JavaScript. What do you think of this approach to OOP in JavaScript?

I know it's possible to do the exact same thing with the class syntax by declaring variables and enclosing them inside the scope of the class' constructor. Which is better though?

---

Here is the full code with an example:

```js
// creating an instance of Person
const person = Person('Nina', 32);

console.log(Object.keys(person));
console.log("person instanceof Person: ", person instanceof Person)


// creating an instance of Singer
const singer = Singer('John', 20, {
  'Little Bird Fly': 'blah'
});

console.log(Object.keys(singer));
console.log("singer instanceof Person: ", singer instanceof Person)
console.log("singer instanceof Singer: ", singer instanceof Singer)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>const Person=(function(){let total=0;let average=0;const updateAverage=function(){average=total/Person.count}
Person.count=0;Person.prototype={sayHi(){return `Hi, I'm ${this.name}`}}
function Person(name,age){const properties={name,gapToAverage(){return Math.abs(age-average)}}
Person.count+=1;total+=age;updateAverage();return Object.create(Object.create(Person.prototype),Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(properties))}
return Person})();const Singer=(function(){let songs={};const prototypeExtension={sing(song){return songs[song]}}
Singer.prototype=Object.create(Person.prototype,Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(prototypeExtension));function Singer(name,age,songs){const properties={getSongTitles(){return Object.keys(songs)}}
return Object.assign(Object.create(Singer.prototype),Person(name,age),properties)}
return Singer})()</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't look as though your `sing` method will function properly.  Nothing updates the in-scope version of `songs` that it uses.  But it also likely doesn't make sense here, since if that *was* updated, then you might get Kanye West singing Elton John's or Marian Anderson's songs... and we don't want to hear that.

Comment: "I know it's possible [to use the built-in syntax]...  Which is better?"  Although I'm not a fan of the class syntax, if it's available to you and does what you want without any additional overhead, I can't see a reason *not* to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine except for the fact it's not super-readable. You may consider other solutions. If you look for private properties, some recommend using ES6 Symbols or WeakMaps. Babel also offers some solutions. For interfaces you can check the [es6-interface npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-interface) or [naive interface implementation using Symbols](https://codeburst.io/interfaces-in-javascript-with-es6-naive-implementation-91b703110a09). I don't know which approach is better, but one of the most important things in OOP for me is readability.